# How to store data from generated text fields

Tags: java, swing

Here's an overview of what I want to do.
The program will accept positive and negative integers to do addition, substraction, multiplication, division.
There will be two jars beside each other, while the numbers are being entered balls will drop in the jar.
If the numbers being entered are positive it will drop in one jar and if the numbers are negative it will drop in the other jar. When the calculation is perform the results of the number of balls will remain in the jar.
Also more than two numbers can be calculated at one time.

It's simple but am not sure what path to take.
Can someone guide me on how to this.
I have started but not sure if am on the right track.
Here's what I did so far.

I have two text field with a drop down to choose the type of operation (x, /, -, +).
An "add" button to add more text field if more numbers are required.
But am not sure how to store those numbers and have the numbers drop the amount of balls as they are enter into the text field.

Any help or ideas would be greatful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand what you are trying to do, it looks like you want to have a sort of visual calculator with a variable number of operations per calculation.

While many may argue this, an easy and educational way of doing this would be to create an "Operation" object (class) that holds the entered number and the operation that will be performed (+-*/).

From here there are two approaches that you can take...

**The sane approach:**

Limit the number of operations to a sane number (ie. 8) and create a statically sized array ( ie. Operation[] ops = new Operation[8]; ) and for every new operation up to the limit, add it to the array.

Once you do this you can either keep a counter of entries or search through the array until you hit an uninitialized index then sort the operations by precedence (+ then - then * then /...) and run the calculation.

**The not-so-sane approach:**

Unlimited operations!  The same thing as previous only using an ArrayList ( [ArrayList, java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ) and once you have the total number of entries, do the same as above.

Happy coding ;)

Comment: Why do you consider using an ArrayList "not-so-sane"?

Comment: Its not absolutely insane but I felt that while it was educational it was kind of overkill for the situation.